# AVG isolated a virus now non on Vista startup I get BHO.DLL not found. how do I fix this error?

Tags: windows-vista, dll

I had to run AVG to clear a virus but now when I start my laptop it gives a message of

This application has failed to start because of BHO.DLL was not found.
Re-installing this application may fix this problem.

How do I turn off this message?  I am getting this everytime I start up the system.

Answer (score 2):

Start -> and type in the box: `msconfig` . Go to Startup and disable what you may suspect (if you fail to pinpoint it, you can easily re-enable them later).

Other way is to use [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) which first, lets you to edit startup better, second, it will clean your registry out so this error may disappear after such cleaning.

Comment: I ran ccleaner that did not remove it so I searched and found this advanced system care and that didnt remove it.  I originally tried the msconfig so going back to msconfig and start unchecking more boxes.  

What the message is stating is ie3sh.exe unable to locate component
but I dont know what thing under msconfig is associated with ie3sh.exe?

Comment: I did a system search and it does not show a file named ie3sh.exe either.

Comment: Post us a screenshot from CCLeaner's startup list (since thats more compact, fits to one screen usually).

Comment: Okay it seems its a crappy company which makes such things: http://www.freefixer.com/library/file/40972/ ... this comment: http://www.freefixer.com/library/file/40972/#comment1415

Comment: Thanks for the source, finally got that bugger off my machine good riddens!

Answer (score 0):

What seems to be the case is that there are relics of the infection still present.
The file bho.dll is gone, but there are still references to it in the registry.

Some advice I can offer:

Use [Revo Uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) to completely uninstall any of the following if you have them:

```
Tattoodle on Facebook and MySpace,  
My Web Tattoo,  
My Tattoons,  
MyFace LOL,  
Tattoodle Skins,  
Get Rated,  
Fast Browser Search toolbar,  
Search Guard Plus Updater,  
Search Guard Plus.
```

Follow uninstall instructions for Search Guard Plus found [here](http://help.fastbrowsersearch.com/).

Get the free [SpyBHORemover](http://securityxploded.com/bhoremover.php) program (needs no install, previously called BHORemover).
Uninstall any BHO (Browser Help Object) that seems to belong to the above list (google them all to be sure).

Scan the computer with [Malwarebytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org/).